# Why is the JSP page not rendered while deploying a SpringBoot App in Pivotal Web Services while it works fine with Thymeleaf and other views

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

The application is deployed in pivotal web services and when I hit the application with the link https://webstore.cfapps.io/, the login.jsp page is not rendered.

The same application runs successfully in the local server. I tried for searching the same issue but none of them solve the problem. I used both STS deployment and also  tried cf command line for deploying separately but couldn't get the result.

I am giving you the details.

1. The error shown.

**Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sat Jan 14 04:21:40 UTC 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp**

2. **My pom file is**

   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   4.0.0

   ecommerce.com
   webstore
   0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   jar

   ecommerce-webstore
   Demo project for Spring Boot

   org.springframework.boot
       spring-boot-starter-parent
       1.4.2.RELEASE

   UTF-8
       UTF-8
       1.8

   org.springframework.boot</groupId> spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
           </dependency> -->
       
           org.springframework.boot
           spring-boot-starter-web

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
       <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
       <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>


   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

   org.springframework.boot
               spring-boot-maven-plugin

3.**MY application.properties file is**

spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/

spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecommercestore

spring.datasource.username=root

spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

**3.The manifest.yml generated after deployment is**
  applications:

- name: webstore

  memory: 1024M

  host: webstore

  domain: cfapps.io

  buildpack: standard buildpack provided in git hub. I am not writing link

  services:

  - cleardb

**The result after giving the following command from cmd is**

*cf push webstore -p target/webstore-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --no-start*

......................................................................
C:\Users\santosh dahal\Desktop\excellerant\ecommerce-webstore>cf push webstore -p target/webstore-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --no-start

Creating app webstore in org santosh-org / space Myspace as santoshdahal2072@gmail.com...
OK

Using route webstore.cfapps.io
Binding webstore.cfapps.io to webstore...
OK

Uploading webstore...

Uploading app files from: C:\Users\SANTOS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\unzipped-app904639435

Uploading 478.9K, 140 files

Done uploading
OK

**6. I went to myapp in pivotal and started the application  after binding the database cleardb to the same instant and application, the application runs successfully with the *Running* Status**

**7. the folder arrangement is as follows:**

I have kept jsp pages in 
**src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp**

While the application.properties is in **src/main/resources**.

I will provide more details if needed. the github link for the code is

[here](https://github.com/santoshdahal12/Ecommerce-webstore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are packaging it as a jar not as a war . In that case put your jsp files into static folder under resources or follow the below the link to understand better on the packaging aspect. But I feel it is better to package it as a war

[Package a spring boot application including JSPs and static resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121918/package-a-spring-boot-application-including-jsps-and-static-resources).

Also please check the jar generated before pushing the app to PWS whether jsp is avaibale at the requested path.

Comment: Thanks for that. Infact I did the same packaging before also but I was deploying from STS which created the problem. Now with the same packaging as you have said I deployed with cf command line  and its working.  About packaging as war, guess the Spring Boot have this notion of preferring packaging as a jar than war. I am not sure which one is best practice?