# WEB-INF not included in WebApp using SpringBoot, Spring-MVC and Maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a webapp using Spring-MVC built with Maven. When I generate the JAR file the app start just fine. The controller is execute but when I reach this part:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test-block", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView block(Model model) {
    return new ModelAndView("templates/test-block");
}
```

I get this error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/templates/test-block.jsp
```

Note that debugging or running in the IDE works fine.

My folder:

```
src
|--main
   |--java
      |--com.xxx // sources
      webapp
      |--WEB-INF
         |--templates
            |--*.jsp // jsp files
      resources
      |--application.properties
```

My application properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I checked the generated JAR file and I can't see WEB-INF anywhere.

**edit:**

pom file:

```
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be generating a .war file?

Comment: I wanted a standalone jar file. But tried doing a war file and now that folder is included. Weird

Comment: Use a request mapper which returns a simple String value (view name) or set the model name and value at the constructor of the `ModelAndView` object.

Comment: A single jar file is not a stand alone web application. Just a module which you can reuse in web applications if you include them into the classpath of a web app packaged into a WAR/EAR file.

Comment: @TheBitman yes, Spring Boot applications are typically bundled as a single jar file, that contains an embedded web server.

Comment: 1. There is no such thing as a WEB-INF directory when you use jar files. 2. You need to avoid using JSPs, or at the very least read and understand the warnings about its usage in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: @JBNizet "I have a webapp using Spring-MVC built with Maven." Spring-boot is just mentioned as a tag and I did not notice it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create a `.war` rather than a `.jar` for a web application and you will see the `WEB-INF` folder.

Also change

`spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/`
to
`spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/templates`
and

`ModelAndView("templates/test-block")` to `ModelAndView("test-block")` to address the 404 error.

Comment: The modelAndView is actually working. I was getting the 404 because the WEB-INF wasn't included in the JAR so test-block.jsp was missing. Created a WAR and now all the files are included. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Reference the Spring Boot documentation on [serving static content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).

Of note:

> By default, Spring Boot serves static content from a directory called
>   /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the
>   classpath or from the root of the ServletContext. It uses the
>   ResourceHttpRequestHandler from Spring MVC so that you can modify that
>   behavior by adding your own WebMvcConfigurer and overriding the
>   addResourceHandlers method.

...

> You can also customize the static resource locations by using the
>   spring.resources.static-locations property (replacing the default
>   values with a list of directory locations).

...

> Do not use the src/main/webapp directory if your application is
>   packaged as a jar. Although this directory is a common standard, it
>   works only with war packaging, and it is silently ignored by most
>   build tools if you generate a jar.

So, what you're seeing is the expected behavior.  You can either move your templates to one of the expected locations, customize the default locations, or use war packaging.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot looks for resources folder for web pages. Webapp folder is not in classpath of spring boot app. You need to use a maven plugin to copy your webapp folder into the jar/war file.
It works in IDE since it knows exactly where to find the web pages.